# React-Redux remove object of array synchronous

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following example saved in a array in redux:

```
example: [
  { type: "A", value: 25 },
  { type: "B", value: 23 },
  { type: "C", value: 324 },
  { type: "A", value: 25 },
]
```

As you can see, some of the objects may appear multiple-times, this should not be changed.
Now i try to remove an specific objects from the list without using the index. This is quite easy, because i can check if the object is the object to remove based on the comparsion below:

```
example[0] == example[2]  // => false
example[0] === example[2] // => false

example[0] == example[0]  // => true
example[0] === example[0] // => true
```

The problem is the aynchronous behavior of [].filter which i use to remove a entry in my reducer as you can see implemented here:

```
case EXAMPLE.REMOVE:
    return state.filter((obj) => obj !== action.payload.objectToRemove)
```

Because when i remove the entries very fast, it sometimes happen than a entry may was removed during the filter but another filter-function also currently runs and then the previously removed object from the other filter-function will be back in the state.
How can i ensure that the reducer works synchronous to avoid such racing-conditions or is there even a more elegant way?

PS: I'm quite sure that the asynchronous-behavior of redux is wanted and the right-way to do it, may i need an other

Edit: I was able to solve the problem due to the fact, that as described in the comments it was not caused by an async call of the reducer but by a rerender of each component caused by the fact that i've not assigned a key and all entries which came after the entry to remove were unmounted and mounted again in the ui were rendered a component per entry of the array. Seems like i missunderstood the real causing problem at this point.

Comment: array.filter is synchronous, and so are redux reducers in general. A race condition should be impossible from the information you've given us. You may need to give us more context.

Comment: Check redux-thunk at https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: I just chekd it what you said @NicholasTower i'm added console-logs before and after the filter-call in the reducer and it seems like they are sequential-executed as you said. Only for some reasons the filter does not remove the entries in some cases. Most of the time it works and sometimes not, especially when the action i dispatch getting more/faster